# R matrix plot or heat map

Tags: r, matrix

I have students score in a matrix:

```
            Q1         Q2      Q3
stdnt1       1          1       4
stdnt2       0          0       5
stdnt3       1          2       3

maxmark      1          2       5
```

I want to plot a matrix plot or heat map to visually show scores. if a student has scored 1 out of 1 that cell is green. in case if 0 is scored, cell is red. and anything in between yellow.
I have used heatmap() in R but it could not help me to compare with max marks. I dont know what is suitable for this plot a matrixplot or  heatmap. Somebody plz help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `heatmap.2` from gplots, it has more adaptations for use.

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(your_matrix, breaks=c(-1,0.1,1.1,6),
          col=c("red","green","yellow"), Rowv=F, Colv=F,
          dendrogram="none", scale="none", trace="none")
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a swift answer. I am almost there. But one issue here is each column has different max mark. the colouring breaks are not same across the matrix. for example column 1 has 1 as a max mark and column 3 has 5 as max marks. This means the rule for column 1 is all 1s are green and 0s red. but for column 3 all 5s are green and 0s are red and in between are yellows. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: You can divide each column by its max column value, then any 1 becomes green , 0 red and otherwise yellow.

Comment: You mean to change this: breaks=c(-1,0.1,1.1,6)? I tried like: breaks=matrix$max and get error

Comment: Hurrey, i used this: sweep(matrix1, 2, matrix2, `/`) and it did the wonder